# Change logo alignment sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, sidebar

Is there a way to set the html logo to the centre of the sidebar?

I have looked around, but cannot find this option, does it exist?

Answer (score 0):

To change the style of the HTML of your Sphinx project, you need to adjust the CSS of your theme.
You can do this by setting the `html_style` variable in your project's `conf.py` file to reference a custom style sheet, as described [here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-html_style) in the Sphinx documentation.
The exact CSS rules you need to apply depend on the HTML theme you are using.